# Proper definition of Berry curvature

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, definition, curvature

I see at least two different definitions of Berry curvature in literature. One is given at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_connection_and_curvature)
$$
\Omega_n = i\sum_{n\ne n'}\frac{ \langle n|\partial_{k_x} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_y} H|n\rangle - \langle n|\partial_{k_y} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_x} H|n\rangle}{(E_n-E_{n'})^2}
$$
The other one is given in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8043) (also given some other articles)
$$
\Omega_n = -2\:Imag\sum_{n\ne n'}\frac{ \langle n|\partial_{k_x} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_y} H|n\rangle}{(E_n-E_{n'})^2}
$$
I wonder what exactly is the difference between these two definitions.

Edit: The article that I mentioned above actually defines the Berry curvature similar to Wikipedia (as pointed out by @NDewolf). One article that defines Berry curvature differently is [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3879) (paragraph below eq24)

Comment: When i look at the paper you refer to, eq. 43a says exactly the same as Wikipedia.

Comment: @NDewolf When they define Berry curvature as $\Omega_n = i\langle \partial_{k_x} n|\partial_{k_y}n\rangle$, they both are equal. But when they define it in terms of derivatives of Hamiltonian, they reach two different definitions (as given above). For example, eq.43a of the article that I mentioned is different from that Wikipedia.

Comment: Eq43a just uses a Levi-Civita symbol to make everything more elegant.

Comment: @NDewolf Ahan! thank you, I get it. I did not take the other possible outcome of Levi-Civita. However, there are some other articles that take the type of definition that I have written above (I will put one of those articles' link in the question). I have written an answer to prove how these two definitions are equal, please have a look if I am doing everything right. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Note from the first equation that
$$
[\langle n|\partial_{k_x} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_y} H|n\rangle]^*=\langle n|[\partial_{k_y} H]^*|n'\rangle \langle n'|[\partial_{k_x} H)]^*|n\rangle
$$
as $\partial_i H=\frac{1}{\hbar} v_i$, and velocity operator $v_i$ are Hermition so $[\partial_i H]^*=\partial_i H$. So,
$$
[\langle n|\partial_{k_x} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_y} H|n\rangle]^*=\langle n|\partial_{k_y} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_x} H)|n\rangle
$$
and

$$
\Omega_n = i\sum_{n\ne n'}\frac{ \langle n|\partial_{k_x} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_y} H|n\rangle - [\langle n|\partial_{k_x} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_y} H|n\rangle]^*}{(E_n-E_{n'})^2} \\
= i\sum_{n\ne n'}\frac{ 2i\:Imag[\langle n|\partial_{k_x} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_y} H|n\rangle]}{(E_n-E_{n'})^2}\\
= -2\:Imag\sum_{n\ne n'}\frac{ \langle n|\partial_{k_x} H|n'\rangle \langle n'|\partial_{k_y} H|n\rangle}{(E_n-E_{n'})^2}\\
$$

Comment: This seems to be correct.